# Is "Tomorrow, I will buy it" correct?

Tags: grammar, adverbs, time

My brother and I are having a discussion, whether it is grammatically correct (or any native speaker would ever say a sentence):

> Tomorrow, I will buy it.

I think it is not correct, it strikes me as very weird order of words, but he says it's unusual but correct and that native speakers would have no problem constructing sentence like this. Who is right, and why?

Comment: It is perfectly correct. However parts of your question were not correct and that is why it has been edited.

Comment: Tomorrow I may answer this. Today I'll simply furnish a link to [ell.se], which you might find to be an interesting place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct, although I bet most would write this sentence without the comma:

> Tomorrow I will buy it.

In speech, among native speakers it would be more common to use a contraction:

> Tomorrow I'll buy it.

This is completely correct; however, your brother is right: it sounds a bit unusual (depending on context). Putting *tomorrow* at the end of the sentence is probably the most common construction:

> I'll buy it tomorrow.

Comment: It’s a bit unusual on its own, but if _tomorrow_ is being used for contrast or emphasis, it can easily be the most natural and idiomatic way to form the sentence, if we allow for the contraction of _I will_ to _I’ll_: “Hey, don’t laugh! I promise you I can get the money for that scooter within a day. Today I can only look; tomorrow I’ll buy it”. Perhaps not the best example, but you get my drift.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet good points. context is always important.